# Impossible Limit Calculation

Tags: calculus

How can I find the following limit. It seems impossible:$$ \large \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac {\displaystyle \prod_{r=0}^n { \left [ (2(r+1))^2 \ ((2r+1)^2 - x^2) \right ]} }{[2(n+1)]^2 \ [(2n+1)!]^2} $$

Comment: Does taking $\log$ help?

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin I have another approach to this. I'm working on it. Can you post yours too?

Comment: @lauren I don't think it is impossible. It just takes some thinking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the function, $f(x)=\cos x$

Euler factorized $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ as:
$$\frac{\sin x}{x}=\left ( 1-\frac{x}{\pi} \right )\left ( 1+\frac{x}{\pi} \right ) \left ( 1-\frac{x}{2\pi} \right ) \left (1+\frac{x}{2\pi} \right )...$$
Thus:
$$\frac{\sin x}{x}=\prod_{r=1}^{\infty}\left ( 1-\frac{x^2}{(r\pi)^2} \right )$$
Similarly, the roots of $\cos x$ are:
$$\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2},\frac{-3\pi}{2}...$$
We can then write:
$$f(x)=\cos x=\prod_{r=1}^{\infty}\left ( 1-\frac{x^2}{\left(\frac{(2r-1)\pi}{2}\right)^2} \right )=\prod_{r=1}^{\infty}\left ( 1-\left (\frac{2x}{(2r-1)\pi} \right )^2 \right )$$
Now, let $x=\frac{\pi y}{2}$.

We have:
$$f\left(\frac{\pi y}{2}\right)=\prod_{r=1}^{\infty}\left ( 1-\left (\frac{y}{(2r-1)} \right )^2 \right )$$

$$\therefore \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac {\displaystyle \prod_{r=0}^n { \left [ (2(r+1))^2 \ ((2r+1)^2 - x^2) \right ]} }{[2(n+1)]^2 \ [(2n+1)!]^2} =\cos\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)$$

Comment: How'd you know to look at cos x?